# form_for template error when updating via patch method in production only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have an account model with several has_many relationships. My forms use the `build` method for all CRUD actions on these nested resources. Everything works locally; however, when I deploy to Heroku and try to edit any of the resources (including the parent account resource) I get a template error regarding syntax. I'm utilizing rails -v 4.0.3, ruby -v 2.0.0p247, and the Cedar stack on Heroku. Here's my form:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 well well-lg">
      <div class="well well-lg" style="background: #fafafa;">
        <h1 class="form-header">Pets</h1>
      </div>
      <%= form_for ([@account, @account.pets.build]), url: account_pet_path(@pet.account_id, @pet.id), method: :patch do |f| %>
        <div class="well well-lg" style="background: #fafafa;">
          <%= f.label  :Name %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :name, :value => @pet.name  %><br>
          <%= f.label :Type %><br>
          <%= f.select :kind, options_for_select(['dog', 'cat', 'rabbit', 'fish', 'bird', 'hamster', 'gerbil', 'guineau pig', 'other']) %><br>
          <%= f.label "Breed or kind" %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :breed, :value => @pet.breed %>
        </div>
        <div class="well well-lg" style="background: #fafafa;">
          <%= f.label :Age %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :age, :value => @pet.age %><br>
          <%= f.label "Birth month" %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :birth_month, :value => @pet.birth_month %>
        </div>
        <div class="well well-lg" style="background: #fafafa;">
          <%= f.label "Health history" %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :health_history, :value => @pet.health_history %><br>
          <%= f.label "Current health" %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :current_health, :value => @pet.current_health %>
        </div>
        <div class="well well-lg" style="background: #fafafa;">
          <%= f.label :Medications %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :med_name, :value => @pet.med_name %><br>
          <%= f.label "Medication procedure" %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :med_administer, :value => @pet.med_administer %><br>
          <%= f.label "Medication doses" %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :med_dose, :value => @pet.med_dose %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :med_frequency, :value => @pet.med_frequency %>
        </div>
        <div class="well well-lg" style="background: #fafafa;">
          <%= f.label :Behavior %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :behavior, :value => @pet.behavior %>
        </div>
        <p>
          <%= f.submit :value => 'Update pet', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
          <%= link_to 'Back', account_dashboard_path(@pet.account_id), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here are the errors I'm getting in the Heroku log file:

ActionView::Template::Error (/app/app/views/pets/edit.html.erb:8: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_end

...id, @pet.id), method: :patch do |f| @output_buffer.safe_appe...

/app/app/views/pets/edit.html.erb:50: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input):

```
5:         <h1 class="form-header">Pets</h1>
6:       </div>
7:
8:       <%= form_for ([@account, @account.pets.build]), url: account_pet_path(@pet.account_id, @pet.id), method: :patch do |f| %>
9:         <div class="well well-lg" style="background: #fafafa;">
10:           <%= f.label  :Name %><br>
11:           <%= f.text_field :name, :value => @pet.name  %><br>
```

It doesn't like the `do` and it's complaining about expecting the `keyword_end` in the last line of my code (erb:50 syntax error). But there's definitely an `<% end %>` there to close out the `do`. Am I missing something obvious? Is there some sort of weirdness with Heroku and the way I have this configured? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have closed parentheses before time. The correct syntax should be:

```
<%= form_for ([@account, @account.pets.build], url: account_pet_path(@pet.account_id, @pet.id), method: :patch) do |f| %>
```

But you could also improve it, given that you already have a pet created. No need to create one in the form:

```
    <%= form_for ([@account, @pet], url: account_pet_path(@pet.account_id, @pet.id), method: :patch) do |f| %>
```